# Conditional form according to choice of dropdown list

Tags: django, forms, conditional-formatting, dropdownlistview

I need a form to be displayed depending on the option chosen in the dropdown list, which will be selected by the administrator when creating the new candidate.

However, the problem is that even if you select any option in the dropdown list, form 2 corresponding to the else of the conditional is displayed. help please.

models.py:

Here the model is defined as well as functions to be able to rename the files when saving them

```
cc= (
        ('1','Quebrada Blanca'),
        ('2','Lo Pinto'),
        ('3','Oficina Central'),
        ('4','Carbonato'),
        ('5','Toconao'),
        ('6','Centinela'),
        ('7','Spence'),
        ('8','La Negra'),

def create_path(instance, filename, file_type):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    new_filename = "DSR_%s_%s_%s_0.%s" % (instance.rut, instance.nombre, file_type, ext)
    return os.path.join('uploads',new_filename)

def imagen_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return create_path(instance, filename, 'imagen')

def certificado_antecedentes_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return create_path(instance, filename, 'certificado_antecedentes')

def hoja_de_vida_conductor_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return create_path(instance, filename, 'hoja_de_vida_conductor')

def certificado_residencia_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return create_path(instance, filename, 'certificado_residencia')

def certificado_afiliacion_afp_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return create_path(instance, filename, 'certificado_afiliacion_afp')

def certificado_afiliacion_salud_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return create_path(instance, filename, 'certificado_afiliacion_salud')

def fotocopia_cedula_identidad_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return create_path(instance, filename, 'fotocopia_cedula_identidad')

def fotocopia_licencia_conducir_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return create_path(instance, filename, 'fotocopia_licencia_conducir')






class Candidato(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 70, null=True, blank=True)
    rut = models.CharField(max_length = 10, primary_key=True)
    correo = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    centro_de_costo =models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length =30, choices = cc)
    estado = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to=imagen_upload_path, null=True, blank=True)
    certificado_antecedentes = models.FileField(upload_to=certificado_antecedentes_upload_path, null=True, blank=True )
    hoja_de_vida_conductor = models.FileField(upload_to=hoja_de_vida_conductor_upload_path, null=True, blank=True)
    certificado_residencia = models.FileField(upload_to=certificado_residencia_upload_path, null=True, blank=True)
    certificado_afiliacion_afp = models.FileField(upload_to=certificado_afiliacion_afp_upload_path, null=True, blank=True)
    certificado_afiliacion_salud = models.FileField(upload_to=certificado_afiliacion_salud_upload_path, null=True, blank=True)
    fotocopia_cedula_identidad = models.FileField(upload_to=fotocopia_cedula_identidad_upload_path, null=True, blank=True)
    fotocopia_licencia_conducir = models.FileField(upload_to=fotocopia_licencia_conducir_upload_path, null=True, blank=True)
    
   
    
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name="candidato"
        verbose_name_plural="candidatos"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre +" "+ self.rut
      
    )
```

forms.py:

Here the 2 forms that share labels are defined, but one contains more labels than the other.

```
class Candidato_form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Candidato

        fields = [
            
            'certificado_antecedentes',
            'hoja_de_vida_conductor',
            'certificado_residencia',
            'certificado_afiliacion_afp',
            'certificado_afiliacion_salud',
            'fotocopia_cedula_identidad',
            'fotocopia_licencia_conducir',
            
            
            

        ]

        labels = {
            
            'certificado_antecedentes': 'Certificado Antecedentes',
            'hoja_de_vida_conductor': 'Hoja de vida del conductor',
            'certificado_residencia': 'Certificado de residencia',
            'certificado_afiliacion_afp': 'Certificado afiliación AFP',
            'certificado_afiliacion_salud': 'Certificado afiliacion de salud',
            'fotocopia_cedula_identidad': 'Fotocopia de cedula de identidad',
            'fotocopia_licencia_conducir': 'Fotocopia de licencia de conducir',
            'curriculum_vitae': 'Curriculum vitae',
            'ultimo_finiquito': 'Ultimo finiquito',
            
            
        }

        widgets = {
            
            'certificado_antecedentes': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'hoja_de_vida_conductor': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'certificado_residencia': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'certificado_afiliacion_afp': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'certificado_afiliacion_salud': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'fotocopia_cedula_identidad': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'fotocopia_licencia_conducir': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            
                  
        }

        
class Candidato_form2(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Candidato

        fields = [
            
            'certificado_antecedentes',
            'hoja_de_vida_conductor',
            

        ]

        labels = {
            
            'certificado_antecedentes': 'Certificado Antecedentes',
            'hoja_de_vida_conductor': 'Hoja de vida del conductor',
        
        }

        widgets = {
            
            'certificado_antecedentes': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'hoja_de_vida_conductor': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            
        }
```

views.py:

This is where the conditional view is defined to select which form is displayed with the Updateview function.

```
class CandidatoList(ListView):
    model = Candidato
    template_name = 'candidato/candidato_list.html'
    paginate_by = 10



class CandidatoUpdate(UpdateView):  
    model = Candidato
    template_name = 'candidato/candidato_form.html'
    success_url = 'http://www.excon.cl'

    def get_form_class(self):
        if self.centro_de_costo == "Lo Pinto":
            return Candidato_form
        else:
            return Candidato_form2
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution you're looking for isn't Django native, from what I know.

A way to implement that would be to use JavaScript event listeners on your form, so that when the user changes the value of field A, it triggers an Ajax call to an endpoint with field A's value, and return the accepted possible values for field B, which you feed to your HTML.

Django will initialize for you the form, but can't edit it "on the fly" once the page has loaded.